# Need to join a third table for detail summing

Tags: sql, db2-400

the data that is created has summary totals like Invoice Amount. Now we don't want invamt but the invamt without the freight charges. Each detail row has a part#, qty, and sale price. We need to join det_table on the otord# = idord#.

But also to sum the det_table, per order, the idprt# must not start with 'FRT' thats how we know freight. I am not sure what sort of join i think left outer.
I then need to include in the first line below, the (qty* sale_price as lintot where idprt# does not start with 'FRT') but then also sum this lintot for the order#.

```
 CREATE VIEW CLSPAYTP AS SELECT OTCOM#, OTORD#, OTTRND, OTTRT, INVAMT,     
    IHORG$, IHORD$, IHINV#,                                   
    OTUSRN, OTTRNC, IHPTTC, IHSLR#, IHORDT,       
    IHDOCD, RFCAT, RFSLC,                                                  
    RFSQ2, RFDTA                                      
    FROM AZLIB.CLSPAYTPP                
                         WHERE         
    OTTRNC='001'                                                             
    UNION                                                      
     SELECT                                             
    OTCOM#, OTORD#, OTTRND, OTTRT, INV       
    INVAMT, IHORG$, IHORD$,IHINV#, OTUSRN, OTTRNC, IHPTTC,
    IHSLR#, IHORDT,      

    IHDOCD, RFCAT, RFSLC, RFSQ2, RFDTA FROM                               
    AZLIB.CLSPAYTPP OT1         
    WHERE OTTRT = (SELECT MIN(OTTRT)                                        
                   FROM AZLIB.CLSPAYTPP OT2              

      WHERE OT2.OTTRNC<>'001' AND OT1.OTORD#= OT2.OTORD#                         
                    GROUP BY OT2.OTORD#)
```

Comment: Please supply table structures (and identify the relevant columns if they have cryptic names) otherwise it is nearly impossible for someone to help you.

Comment: The view above is not indexed or keyed, the oeind2 is key by the order number.